# Returned 404 Not Found when request user email [ASP.NET Web API]

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to get user email from ASP.NET Web API through writing an email in an input box using JQuery (to select message recipients), But the returned value is null. Are there any problems in passing process in my code?

Web API:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("get-reciver-email")]
        public ApplicationUser GetReciverEmailId([FromUri] string email)
        {
            return _userManager.FindByEmail(email);

        }
```

Client-side "JQuery":

```
$('#toEmail').keyup(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/Account/get-reciver-email/' + $("#toEmail").val(),
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    // Display errors if any in the Bootstrap alert <div>
                    error: function (jqXHR) {
                        $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#divError').show('fade');
                    }
                });
            });
```

I expect to return user info based on passed email in HTML form.

Comment: Try specifying the absolute URL in the ajax request (or check the network tab to make sure the request made is correct). If this doesn't work, please post here the route registrations you have.

Comment: However, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-fromuri) states `[FromUri]` is used for complex types hence I would remove it and add the email as a query-string `'/api/Account/get-reciver-email?email=' + $("#toEmail").val()`.

Comment: All routes in app working correctly, except this. I doubt that the problem is in the passing process from client-side, Here's Network & console tab:
https://i.imgur.com/shcyc7S.png

Comment: OK, I will try.

Comment: I removed [FromUri] & added ?email=' + $("#toEmail").val(). And now an exception occur! : https://i.imgur.com/v5OcPjz.png

Comment: Try using AttributeRoutes: `[Route("get-reciver-email/{email}")]`. That should do it.

Comment: THX, I solved the problem below.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I removed [FromUri] & I used query-string (THX for @Mihai), also I modified API function to the following:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
[Route("get-reciver-email")]
public string GetReciverEmailId(string email)
{
    return   db.Users.Where(x => x.Email == email).Select(x => x.Id).Single();

}
```

Client-side code:

```
$('#toEmail').keyup(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/api/Account/get-reciver-email/?email=' + $("#toEmail").val(),
                    method: 'GET',
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    // Display errors if any in the Bootstrap alert <div>
                    error: function (jqXHR) {
                        $('#divErrorText').text(jqXHR.responseText);
                        $('#divError').show('fade');
                    }
                });
            });
```